# Saving single object properties in sharedPreferences

Tags: android, json, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to use SharedPreferences to save each object and then later load that specific object?
I have a list of objects that I've managed to save with SharedPreferences (Using RecyclerView to display them) and when I select any of these objects from that list, a new activity will open and that object will be passed as an argument. What I'm trying to do is add to the list of that specific object (Each object has a Mutable List property) and then store that list in SharedPreferences.
I've managed to do it, but the problem is my list will be saved into a "global" list and each item will load the exact same list. How could I associate SavedPreference with that specific object and then load the list for that specific object as well? I'm attaching image of the app so that you can better understand what I mean.

**SingleListActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.simpleshoppinglist

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.simpleshoppinglist.adapter.ShoppingItemAdapter
import com.example.simpleshoppinglist.data.Datasource
import com.example.simpleshoppinglist.model.ShoppingItem
import com.example.simpleshoppinglist.model.SingleLista
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

val activityIntentId: Int = 1


class SingleListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   
    //Empty init
    var singleList = SingleLista ("Placeholder")
    var listSource = singleList.listOfShoppingItems
    var shoppingItemAdapter = ShoppingItemAdapter(this, singleList.listOfShoppingItems)
    lateinit var lblTest: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_list)
        // LABEL ZA TESTIRANJE - 2 LINIJE
        val lblTestni: TextView = findViewById(R.id.TESTNILABEL)
        lblTest = lblTestni

        val getObjectFromRecyclerOnClick = intent.getSerializableExtra("Extra_object") as SingleLista
        singleList = getObjectFromRecyclerOnClick
        loadData()

        listSource = singleList.listOfShoppingItems
        shoppingItemAdapter = ShoppingItemAdapter(this, singleList.listOfShoppingItems)
        var recyclerViewSingle = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view_single)
        val btnAddShoppingItem: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnDodajNamirnicu)
        recyclerViewSingle.adapter = shoppingItemAdapter


        btnAddShoppingItem.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, AddShoppingItemActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("SinglLista", singleList)
            this.startActivityForResult(intent, activityIntentId)
        }
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == activityIntentId) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //var testniLabel: TextView = findViewById(R.id.TESTNILABEL)
                //testniLabel.text = "TEST LABEL"
                var shoppingItemName = data?.getSerializableExtra("NazivNamirnice") as String
                var shoppingItemQuantity = data?.getSerializableExtra("KolicinaNamirnice") as String
                addShoppingItem(
                    shoppingItemName,
                    shoppingItemQuantity,
                    shoppingItemAdapter,
                )

                saveData()

            }
        }

    }

    fun saveData (){
        var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Liste_u_objektu", MODE_PRIVATE)
        var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        var gson = Gson()
        var json: String = gson.toJson(singleList.listOfShoppingItems)
        editor.putString("Spremi_Objekt", json)
        editor.apply()
        //lblTest.text = singleList.naziv TEST LABEL
    }

    fun loadData(){
        var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Liste_u_objektu", MODE_PRIVATE)
        var gson = Gson()
        if (sharedPreferences.getString("Spremi_Objekt", null) != null){
            var json: String = sharedPreferences.getString("Spremi_Objekt", null)!!
            val turnsType = object : TypeToken<MutableList<ShoppingItem>>() {}.type
            singleList.listOfShoppingItems = gson.fromJson(json,turnsType)
            shoppingItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        else{
            listSource.clear()
        }
    }

    fun addShoppingItem(
        shoppingItemName: String,
        shoppingItemQuantity: String,
        adapter: ShoppingItemAdapter,
    ) {
        singleList.listOfShoppingItems.add(ShoppingItem(
            shoppingItemName,
            shoppingItemQuantity.toInt()
        ))
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

[image: Activity Screens]

**Edit:** Perhaps each object should have its own SharedPreference ? What If I made a unique identifier for each object?

**Edit 2:** I have managed to resolve the issue by creating a unique identifier for SharedPreference key. In my case it was Shopping List name, then I would prevent the user from adding 2 lists with the same name.

Comment: What about saving it as string by serializing the object by Gson()? Or what about applying an easy to use orm database, such as litepal?

Comment: I believe just as you have described, you can check in the code. I'd first try to complete this project by using SharedPreferences only.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue by creating a unique identifier for SharedPreference key. In my case it was Shopping List name, then I would prevent the user from adding 2 lists with the same name.